# Python Correlation Analysis of 2 data sets

Tags: python

I currently try to put the following time series into one plot, with adjusted scalings to examine whether they correlate or not.

```
raw = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jens/Documents/Studium/Master/Big Data Analytics/Lecture 5/tr_eikon_eod_data.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
data = raw[['.SPX', '.VIX']].dropna()
data.tail()
data.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(10,6));
```

[image]

Has anyone an idea how to do that?

Also, would it possible to do the same with data from two different data sets? I like to compare a house price index with a stock index. I have the daily closing prices for the stock index and just a value for each quarter for the house prices (10y). I.e. closing price against house price index.

I don't really know where to start.

Thank you!:)

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like you're using pandas, have you looked through the documentation and tried implementing any of [dataframe.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html), [corrwith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html#pandas.DataFrame.corrwith) or [series.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html#pandas.Series.corr)?